# Hardwood flooring installation

Tags: flooring, hardwood

We have 1/2” particle board over 3/4” plywood. Can we install real hardwood over both?
We now have carpet which we want to replace.

Comment: If the floor is flat with no dips or ridges then yes.  The new flooring will raise the floor height up a bit ~3/4 inch, but if you are happy with the new height, no problem.

Comment: Answers, answers, @crip659. ;)

Comment: Is this an above grade floor?  Real, solid hardwood usually isn't recommended for basements or other below ground locations.

Comment: Yes it us above grade. I was concerned that the particle board would not hold the nails

Comment: Debbie, I suggest you add the "would not hold the nails" part to the question itself, since it seems to be the main point of your question.

Comment: (I'm not an expert by any means, but I believe that with most tongue-and-groove style flooring, the boards are nailed to each other rather than the subfloor. And if you're concerned about anything that *does* get nailed to the subfloor, I suppose you can get some extra-long nails...)

Answer (score 9):

If the floor is flat with no dips or ridges then yes.

The new flooring will raise the floor height up a bit ~3/4 inch, but if you are happy with the new height, no problem.

Most flooring made with hard materials want a nice flat surface, usually less than 1/32 inch difference under a long flat edge.  Soft type of floors can flow more up and down.